# dotTrace and performance profiling?

Tags: c#, performance, dottrace

I recently re-wrote my file format writing library. I realized my code was messy, made everything way too complicated, and was generally just hard to keep maintained.

So my new library is so much more organized and clean. I realized that many of the ways I accomplished tasks in the old library was WAY more complicated than it needed to be, so I expected my new code to be ALOT faster.

Well, not exactly. I tested performance at first by using the Stopwatch class in the .Net framework. My old library was consistently faster, which shocked me, since there were too many improvements and optimizations to count.

I then tested both using the dotTrace Performance Profiler. As expected, my NEW library was faster - about 2 **times** faster! My old library measured 62 milliseconds, and my new one measured 28 milliseconds!

So I'm not sure what is going on. In Visual Studio my new library is much slower - in fact, it is VERY inconsistent, it will range from a time of 00::00::00.042 to 00::00::00.351!!

Does anyone know why this may be happening? dotTrace says it's 2 times faster, the Stopwatch says it is 2-4 times slower.

Thanks to everyone for your help.

- Alex

EDIT:

The code is the same for both libraries, both just reference the new and old library. This was tested on a Console application:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Textstring txt = new Textstring("TestText");
        txt.Text = "This is a test textstring.";
        RdwFile f = new RdwFile("Test");
        f.Add(txt);
        f.Save();

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
};
```

Comment: We need to see how to used Stopwatch. For example, did you run it first so it was properly JITed, then time a second run? I don't know if dotTrace measures JIT time. I would think it doesn't.

Comment: You can't get good results with such short tests.  Write a test that exercises your code many times and runs for several seconds and compare.

Comment: I ran each test 20 times, for both the Stopwatch method and dotTrace profiler. The old library measured an average of 00::00::00.034 for the Stopwatch and an average of 63 for dotTrace (Profile type: Sampling, Measure: Thread). My new library measured an average of 00::00::00.08, but it really did range from 00::00::00.04 to 00::00::00.3 for the Stopwatch. It measured an average of 30 milliseconds in dotTrace.

Comment: @vcsjones The new library still runs 2 times faster according to dotTrace, it should still be faster (not slower) than the old library.

Comment: you could also try other profilers to compare with dotTrace to see if they agree. Visual Studio Profiler, ANTS Performance Profiler, YourKit, some others too. Though make sure to mimic profiling options (type of timings, i.e. line-level, sampling). I am assuming you are not debugging in VS, and should look at release/optimised code for this.

Comment: Yup, looking at the release builds for both. Visual Studio Profiler and ANTS cost money, no? I think I already used up my trial for ANTS as well. dotTrace has never given me problems and has always been very accurate, so I'm not sure. I'll keep messing around with it to figure out what's going on.

Comment: This might be an obvious advice, but did you look at the profiler data to see **why** the code is slow?

Comment: You could try looking a performance counters: something like [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2635/High-Performance-Timer-in-C) though I would do a test Start/Stop to Jit the methods before actual using.